# Cannot alter table (add unique constraint) in a SQL PL store procedure for db2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, alter-table, sql-pl

I am trying to create a store procedure in SQL PL for db2. A new field needs to be added as part of the unique key, so I need to drop the previous uk first, and then add the new unique key. That worked fine for MS SQLServer and Oracle, but I cannot make it for db2.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_unique_key ()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN 
    DECLARE uk_constraint_name VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE sql_stmt VARCHAR(100);  
    SELECT constname INTO uk_constraint_name FROM SYSCAT.TABCONST WHERE tabname = 'TABLE_NAME' AND type = 'U';
    SET sql_stmt = 'alter table TABLE_NAME drop constraint ' || char(uk_constraint_name);
    SET sql_stmt_2 = 'alter table TABLE_NAME add unique (F1, F2)';  

    prepare s1 from sql_stmt;
    prepare s2 from sql_stmt_2;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE s1;   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE s2;       
END
```

Getting this error when trying to deploy the routine with IBM Data Studio as client (the database is db2 9.5)

```
    DEV.UPDATE_UNIQUE_KEY - Deploy started.
Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -206, SQLSTATE: 42703.
DEV.UPDATE_UNIQUE_KEY: 8: "SQL_STMT_2" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.12.55
"SQL_STMT_2" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.12.55
```

The thing I don't understand is:
- If in the routine I just drop the constraint it works.
- I can add the constraint just doing an alter table from a sql client (Squirrel)
- If I have just a routine trying to add the constraint I get the same error.

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I just forgot to declare the variable...

DECLARE sql_stmt_2 VARCHAR(100);

Comment: so are you saying this answered your question? if so please feel free to post it as an answer so others can see the question has been answered. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to declare the variable... DECLARE sql_stmt_2 VARCHAR(100);